# print() no muestra el mensaje

Tags: python

He hecho un juego de adivina la palabra, y tengo un trozo de código que verifica si ya el usuario ha ingresado una letra antes, se ve así:

```
    if letra in actual:
        clear()
        print('La letra ya se encuentra en la palabra')
        espacio()
        print(' '*10, ' '.join(actual))
        intentos -= 1
        espacio()
        print('Intentos fallidos restantes: ', intentos, '\n')
```

donde

```
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')

def espacio(cantidad=1):
    print('\n'*cantidad)
```

y suponiendo que la palabra a adivinar sea 'ARBUSTO', está:

```
palabra = 'ARBUSTO'
actual = list('_'*len(palabra))
```

básicamente 'actual' construye una lista con '_' tantas letras haya en la palabra, que luego voy reemplazando de acuerdo se van ingresando las letras correctas.

La cosa es que el print() que está entre el clear() y el espacio() nunca muestra el mensaje que debería: 'La letra ya se encuentra en la palabra', de hecho no importa que argumento tenga el print, o si escribo otro, si lo colo allí nunca se muestra en pantalla, tengo estructuras similares a lo largo del programa y todas ellas funcionan a excepción de ésta.

Aquí el código completo

```
import os
import sys
import getpass

def espacio(cantidad=1):
    print('\n'*cantidad)

clear = lambda: os.system('cls')

palabra = getpass.getpass('\nIngrese la palabra a adivinar: ').upper()
intentos = int(input('Número de intentos fallidos permitidos: '))
clear()
espacio(2)
actual = list('_'*len(palabra))
print(' '*10, ' '.join(actual))
espacio(2)


while True:
    if intentos == 0:
        clear()
        print('La palabra era:')
        espacio()
        print(' '*10,' '.join(list(palabra)))
        espacio()
        print('Has perdido \n')
        sys.exit()
        break

    letra = input('Ingrese una letra: ').upper()
    cantidad = palabra.count(letra)

    if letra in palabra:
        posicion = palabra.index(letra)
        izq = len(palabra[:posicion])
        der = len(palabra[posicion+1:])

        if letra in actual:
            clear()
            print('La letra ya se encuentra en la palabra')
            espacio()
            print(' '*10, ' '.join(actual))
            intentos -= 1
            espacio()
            print('Intentos fallidos restantes: ', intentos, '\n')

        actual[posicion] = letra

        if cantidad is not 1:
            for i in range(cantidad-1):
                posicion = palabra.index(letra, posicion+1)
                izq = len(palabra[:posicion])
                der = len(palabra[posicion+1:])
                actual[posicion] = letra

        if actual.count('_') == 0:
            clear()
            print('La palabra es:')
            espacio()
            print(' '*10,' '.join(actual))
            espacio()
            print('Felicidades! Has ganado\n')
            sys.exit()

        clear()
        espacio()
        print(' '*10, ' '.join(actual))
        espacio()
        print('Intentos fallidos restantes: ', intentos)
        espacio()
    else:
        clear()
        print('La letra no se encuentra en la palabra')
        espacio()
        print(' '*10, ' '.join(actual))
        intentos -= 1
        espacio()
        print('Intentos fallidos restantes: ', intentos, '\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro que lo muestra, solo que estar forzando un clear() nuevamente.

```
    #AQUI ARRIBA VAN TODOS LOS IF
    #AQUI ARRIBA VAN TODOS LOS IF
    clear() #AQUI vuelves a limpiar la pantalla
    espacio()
    print(' '*10, ' '.join(actual))
    espacio()
    print('Intentos fallidos restantes: ', intentos)
    espacio()
else:
    clear()
    print('La letra no se encuentra en la palabra')
    espacio()
    print(' '*10, ' '.join(actual))
    intentos -= 1
    espacio()
    print('Intentos fallidos restantes: ', intentos, '\n')
```

¿Cómo me di cuenta? Rompí el while con un **break**

---

## ¿Cómo lo arreglo?

Agregas un **continue** para que no lea lo de más abajo

Quedaría así:

```
if letra in actual:
        clear()
        print('La letra ya se encuentra en la palabra')
        espacio()
        print(' '*10, ' '.join(actual))
        intentos -= 1
        espacio()
        print('Intentos fallidos restantes: ', intentos, '\n')
        continue
```

Comment: Huy! vaya ojo! no me había dado cuenta, la verdad es que para hacerlo ver bonito me volví un poco loco con los clear() y los espacio(). El programa ahora se muestra correctamente, muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Un placer, suerte con su juego!